# Android EditText - Delete the last letter with a button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-button

I have to buttons that writes A and B to an edittext. If there is something in the edittext how can I delete the last letters with the "Del" button?
My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonb"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttona"
    android:text="@string/buttonb"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttona"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/buttona"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttondel"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/buttondel"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="58"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my java:

```
package com.koostamas.keyboard;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button buttona, buttonb;
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

addListenerOnButton();
}


   public void addListenerOnButton() {

buttona = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttona);
buttona.setOnClickListener(this);
buttona.getText();
buttonb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonb);
buttonb.setOnClickListener(this);
buttonb.getText();

   }

public void onClick(View v) {

    Button buttona = (Button)v;
    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString()+buttona.getText().toString());


}

public void onClick1(View v) {

    Button buttonb = (Button)v;
    editText.setText(editText.getText().toString()+buttonb.getText().toString());


}
}
```

So I want to make it. Please help me!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can create an onClickListener and just get the text from edit text and delete the last character.

```
Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttondel);
if( delete != null ) {
   delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick() {
         String textString = editText.getText().toString();
         if( textString.length() > 0 ) {
            editText.setText(textString.substring(0, textString.length() - 1 ));
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());//position cursor at the end of the line
         }
      }
   });
}
```

Edit: Also don't forget to check the string length is greater than 0 before doing this in the event a or b hasn't been pressed when the user hits delete.

Comment: See Gabe's reply to your other comment substring is exclusive so you need -1 not -2.

Comment: Please tell me where should I put it. I couldn't make it. Thanks.

Comment: In your onCreateMethod you need to find your delete button just like you did for ButtonA and ButtonB and then call setOnClick listener on that button as shown above. I've edited the response to show that step

Answer (score 2):

Setting new text#1

```
CharSequence text = edittext.getText();
edittext.setText(text.subSequence(0, text.length() - 1));
```

Setting new text#2

```
CharSequence text = v.getText();
edittext.setText("");
edittext.append(text, 0, text.length() - 1);
```

Deleting editable

```
int length = editText.getText().length();
if (length > 0) {
    editText.getText().delete(length - 1, length);
}
```

Subsequencing editable

```
int length = editText.getText().length();
if (length > 0) {
    editText.getText().subSequence(0, length - 1);
}
```

Deleting by dispatching delete key event.

```
edittext.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = editText.getText().toString();
if(text.length() > 0){
  text = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
   editText.setText(text);
}
```

Comment: substring's ending index is exclusive.  So if you say substring(0,1), the result will only have index 0 in it.  So -1 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

one limitation of others answer is if cursor not in last position then also it delete the last character that limitation is removed in this answer
Write down at your on click of button

```
int end = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.one)).getSelectionEnd();
 if(end>0){
           SpannableStringBuilder selectedStr = new SpannableStringBuilder(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.one)).getText());
           selectedStr.replace(end - 1, end, "");
           ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.one)).setText(selectedStr);
           ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.one)).setSelection(end-1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete last character using this,

Kotlin

```
if (etSearch.text.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
    etSearch.text = Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable((etSearch.text.delete(etSearch.text.toString().length-1, etSearch.text.toString().length)))
}
```